# Making videocamera Eyewear (glasses)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, however:

I would like to know if it's possible to make videocam Eyewear. What I mean:

1. Take simple glasses without lens
2. Instead of lens, use screens on which video from camera will be displayed
3. I build two cameras, one on the left, one on the right,which will capture video to left and right screen.

Can this be done? How can it be done? What is needed to create this?

P. S. Is it also possible to add a zoom in and out feature through an exterior control?

Comment: How does this compare to the Microsoft Hololens product?

Comment: Oh, I'm not aware of any Microsoft projects of the kind. I will read about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more appropriate to photography.se or a physics site

Comment: What has photography to do with this? I was thinking of making such a device. It's engineering.

Comment: [Gear VR](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/gear-vr/), remove front cover and leave it off, insert phone. U$100 + Phone. I can press the volume control on my S9+ and it zooms.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is most of what a Virtual Reality Headset is.  It presents two video signals, one to each eye.  VR headsets are meant to display computer-generated video signals, but it would be a rather small modification to get the two video signals from cameras instead.

One thing you seem to be missing is that projecting a image in the same place where lenses of glasses are doesn't work if you expect to see the image.  It would be way too close for your eyes to focus on.  You need optics between the video screens and the eyes so that the images appear at infinity to the user.

Comment: So the cameras should be on the opposite side of the screens?

Comment: There's an alternative method which involves a scanning light source (e.g. laser) to write the image pattern directly onto the retina.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft How can this be done? How better is it or worse?

Comment: @SovereignSun I don't know if anyone's actively pursuing this approach. It's probably got more moving parts (bad) and alignment sensitivity (bad)